# Finding a line using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping that someone can help me. I have the below code which is not pulling through any results. I am looking to bring through data which will match multiple criteria.

Column B which is a data field
Column AC which (so long as is `null`) I would like the information to display

The first issue is I cannot get it to Search when using a date for column B
The second is when I add the second criteria of Null in column AC I I am getting a Run-Time Error 424 Object Required. Can someone please help me. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Me.txtDate.Value

With Sheets("Acc")
    Set searchRange = Sheets("Acc").Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Offset(0, 27) Is Null Then

            Me.txtRef1 = foundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

        Else

            MsgBox "Reference Does Not Exist"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
mysearch = Me.txtDate.Value
```

with:

```
mysearch = cDate(Me.txtDate.Value)
```

Comment: For the date issue this works, however it is still not liking searching multiple criteria with If Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Offset(0, 27) Is Null Then

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the statement beginning with If Not foundCell causes your error when foundCell is Nothing, because of the error that arises at the same time when it evaluates foundCell.Offset(0, 27).

I suggest separating the foundCell.Offset logic to a nested IF statement.

Also, it seems that your foundCell.Offset test works better if you look for

```
If foundCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = Null then
```

instead of

```
if foundCell.Offset(0, 27) is Null
```

.

Good luck!